# Validate an array from excel file using Laravel validation

Tags: php, excel, laravel, validation, laravel-validation

Hi I wonder if it possible to validate an array like this in laravel:

```
Array
(
    [0] => John
    [1] => 20
    [2] => john@example.com
)
```

because im getting the data from the excel file. I want to validate the `[1] => numeric` and `[2] => email`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom validation like following.

```
Validator::extend('check_my_array', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    $validation = [];
    foreach($parameters as $parameter)
        $validation[] = "required|{$parameter}";

    $validator = Validator::make($value, $validation);
    return !$validator->fails();
});
```

You can create ValidatorServiceProvider and you can add these lines to boot method of ValidatorServiceProvider. Then you need to add Provider to your providers array in config/app.php.

```
App\Providers\ValidatorServiceProvider::class,
```

Or you just add them top of the action of your controller.

At the end you can use it like this in your validation rules.

```
$validator = Validator::make(
  ['array' => ['John', 'asd', 'john@example.com']],
  ['array' => 'check_my_array:,numeric,email']
);

if ($validator->fails())
   dd('fail');
else dd('success');
```

Note: Everything after the check_my_array separated by comma is a parameter we use them specific rule for elements of the array.